# Refresh/update data extension random splits

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, split

I have made a 5 way split based on a data extension, but I can't find anywhere I can refresh this split after its made, like you can with Groups for Lists. 
Anyone know if this is possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a "Random Data Extension", these cannot be refreshed.  Filtered data extension can be refreshed but these random data extensions cannot.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_random_data_extension/